# html5 clip a canvas

Tags: html, html5-canvas

I have a canvas but want to cut out and display only various rectangle sections of this canvas
Im not sure if this is possible? I have seen some people clip an image, but can it be done for a canvas.

Essentially i want to draw rectagles, keep the rectangle bits and discard the rest of the canvas

```
        ctx.save();
        ctx.beginPath();
        ctx.rect(140, 20, 100, 100);
        //ctx.stroke();
        ctx.clip();

       ctx.restore();
```

Comment: Raklos did you try http://www.html5canvastutorials.com/advanced/html5-canvas-clipping-region-tutorial/ ?

Comment: What is your issue ? From your question, it seems you have all cards in hand.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did it like this:

```
        ctx.beginPath();

        for (var i = 0; i < Rectangles.length; i++) {
            var item = Rectangles[i];



            ctx.moveTo(item.x1 , item.y1 );
            ctx.lineTo(item.x1  + item.width  , item.y1 );
            ctx.lineTo(item.x1  + item.width  , item.y1 + item.height  );
            ctx.lineTo(item.x1 , item.y1 + item.height  );
            ctx.lineTo(item.x1 , item.y1 );


        }
        ctx.closePath();
        ctx.clip();
```

And run this before the drawing part.